# Why are there multiple empty paths in this URL file

Tags: python, url

So I am new to Django, and I am learning it using an existing app in my company. When I look at the urls.py I see the following:

```
path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
path('', include(('apps.resource.urls', 'resource'), namespace='resource')),
path('', include(('apps.lib.urls', 'lib'), namespace='lib')),
```

So my question is why are there multiple mappings for `''` ?
I thought it was one pattern and then a url mapping to resolve that pattern. Can anyone help me understand what is happening here?

Comment: You arent seeing a complete path, its building multiple up, just think of it as a filter that directs any string that matches the path so far to those urls until either it matches a path or your url cannot follow any other path

Comment: @Sayse but in that case, wont it always sent it to the first URL? that is, django.contrib.auth.urls?

Comment: Only if one of the urls in that path matches, otherwise it carries down the list